# Hibernate Model: set default @ManyToOne value of a Child Class

Tags: java, hibernate, default-value, class-hierarchy

I have class User which has @ManyToOne field Role.

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="USERS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue("ROLE_ADMIN")
@DiscriminatorColumn (name="ROLENAME", discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING, length=20)
public class User extends BaseEntity implements UserDetails {
    // all others fields like username, password,...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName="id") 
    @NotNull(message = "ROLE field is mandatory")
    private Role role;

    //getter and setter
}
```

I have many classes that extends User: UserSeller, UserClient, UserOffice....

```
@Entity
    @DiscriminatorValue("ROLE_SELLER")
    @AttributeOverride(name = "role", column = @Column(name = "role_id"))
    public class UserSeller extends User {

       //additional fields like CompanyId,...

       //getter & setter
    }
```

I have one panel where i can insert / edit / delete all kind of users,
but i must have also "n" panel: one for each kind of user.

When i'm in these panel, i would like to be able to insert these UserSeller without having
to put a  where to choose role, but i want set this role as default.

• I tried to put a costructor in the UserSeller

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ROLE_SELLER")
@AttributeOverride(name = "role", column = @Column(name = "role_id"))
public class UserSeller extends User {

    @Transient
    RoleService roleService;

    @Transient
    User user = new User();


    public UserSeller()
    {
        super(); 
        try
        {
            this.setRole(roleService.getRole("ROLE_SELLER"));
        }
        catch (RecordNotFoundException e)
        {

        }
    }
```

but i get this error:

```
Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
```

• i tried to pass a User object to constructor:

```
public UserSeller(User user)
```

and in controller i do this:

```
 User user = new User();
 UserSeller seller = new UserSeller(user);
 model.addAttribute("seller", seller);
```

but i get this error:

> No default constructor for entity: com.machinet.model.UserVenditore

- If, in UserSeller i declare again the Role field i get error about
  "Redefined Column"....
- Finally i found this that i though could be my solution (in
  UserSeller class):

  ```
  @PrePersist
  public void prePersist() {
          try
          {
              this.setRole(roleService.getRole("ROLE_SELLER"));
          }
          catch (RecordNotFoundException e)
          {

          }           
      }
  ```

but when i'm in the UserSeller panel and i try to add a new Seller, it doesnt' take the default role and the validation fails.

I would like to know how can i do the trick: i want that my UserSeller, UserClient,... have a default value when i insert a new record.

Do i really need to do this in the controller? is this the only way? because for a beginner like me, it doesn't look so so elegant solution:

```
UserVenditore venditore = new UserVenditore();
try
{
    venditore.setRole(roleService.getRole("ROLE_VENDITORE"));
}
catch (RecordNotFoundException ex)
{

}
model.addAttribute("venditore", venditore);
```

edit: also this last solution doesn't work: it fails the validation!

Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: On side note, it is usually better to separate your model and services. Having a RoleService within an entity class is bad practice IMO.

Comment: thanks @JamesB for your suggestion. it's always good get these advices

Answer (score 0):

for now, i found only this solution (in the ControllerClass):

- in removed @Valid before @ModelAttribute
- i manually set the role
- i manually validate the object

  @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String addingSeller(@ModelAttribute UserSeller seller,
          BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {

  ```
  logger.info("IN: Seller/add-POST"); 

  //set role
  try
  {
      seller.setRole(roleService.getRole("ROLE_SELLER"));
  }
  catch (RecordNotFoundException ex)
  {

  }        

  //validation
  validator.validate(seller, result);

  if (result.hasErrors()) {
      logger.info("Seller-add error: " + result.toString());
      redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.seller", result);            
      redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("seller", seller);

  } else {

      try
      {
          SellerService.addSeller(seller);

          //message to the user
          String message = "Seller added!";           
          redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("message", message);
          redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("message_class", "alert-success");      
      }
      catch (DuplicateRecordException e)
      {
          //the username already exists

          //message to the user
          String message = "Already exists an user with this USERNAME";           
          redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("message", message);
          redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("message_class", "alert-danger");         

          redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("seller", seller);
      }
  }   

  return "redirect:/sellers/list";
  ```

  }

Comment: Another tip: Push all the logic to set the default role and validate the seller into the SellerService, that's what it is there for. Imagine having another piece of code which calls the service and wants the same logic to be applied.